# Mapping all members of an enum class to something at compile time

Tags: c++, enums, c++20

There could have been easy solutions (like [magic-enum](https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum)) if I only ever wanted to map enums to strings for printing. That is unfortunately not the case.

I could think of three possibilites:

First, generate some constexpr map (like [this one](https://github.com/mapbox/eternal)) from a list of enum values and a list of something else. This has the obvious disadvantage that someone needs to keep the list up-to-date. Some of these enums come from 3rd party libraries. `boost::Describe` would have the same issue.

Second, generate switch case from the two lists at compile time. With `-Wswitch`, the compiler would complain if not all cases are handled. Makes a lot of sense. But I cannot seem to find any way of doing it.

Third, generate a map, not from the list, but from the enum class directly, which is a very unreliable method, because those enums are not written by me and there is no general assumption I can make about underlying types, contiguousness, etc. Magic-enum is likely to suffer due to the same limitation(s).

The only way that works currently is to manually write switch-cases. Is there a more elegant solution possible? Could I detect if all enum members are handled without using switch-cases?

Comment: There are no reflection (yet) in C++. Note also that enum can take value which are not given directly in the possibility (as long it fits the underlying type) (thing about enum *flag*).

Comment: I do not think reflection helps me iterate over enum members. Or did I get that wrong?

Comment: @SubhamoyS. it will do yes.